# Gephi not displaying graph from gremlin console .......1. error

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gephi

Ibeen tinkering with Gremlin console and was trying to visualize graph created in gremlin console through Gephi(V0.1)and gremlin 3.7.
I followed the instruction from Tinkerpop tutorials.
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#gephi-plugin

installed graph streaming pluggins and created workspace and I can see in console it is connecting to Gephi.I saw the graph with first attempt.But no graph whatsoever after.
I see a response for :>graph
`:>graph ......1>`
Anyone knows what this error is?

I tried to restart gephi several times .It is not giving any errors. I tried with with both Tinker-pop gremlin console and Janus-graph gremlin consoles. No luck

Comment: I'm not sure what might be going on with Gephi. I used to use it a lot but lately not so much. There are some alternatives to using Gephi if you add a Gremlin Server to you configuration. In GitHub you will find the [graph-explorer](https://github.com/aws/graph-explorer) and [graph-notebook](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook) open source projects that can be used to query and visualize a TinkerPop/Gremlin graph.

Comment: You referenced a very old version of the documentation. I'm not sure if there is something in those docs that is out of date, but you say you're using TinkerPop 3.7.1 so you should probably be looking at that documentation: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.7.1/reference/#gephi-plugin in particular, i think somewhere along the line the default workspace became "workspace1" rather than "workspace0" so if you followed the old instructions the URL you were using might need to change.